# Combining multiple Haar Classifiers with OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, cascade, classification

I was wandering if there is a way to combine Haar-Classifiers from different trained cascades?
I have a scenario, where I detect one object that differs depending on the angle of the object. So I separated my training samples to train multiple classifiers. They work OK for their classes. Right now I run them sequentially which is costing me a lot of calculation time.

I figured that OpenCV is probably calculating all the features every time thus iterating newly every time. I thought, if I could combine my classifiers by an OR operation, then OpenCV might be able to just use one cascade thus only iterating once and only calculating the needed features once and so on. This might increase my performance dramatically. However I am not sure if (and how) this could be done. Maybe someone else has tried something similar before?

Cheers! 
-- artur

Answer (score 2):

Well, when you train a specific classifier, AdaBoost algorithm (at every stage) picks different features to minimize training error. That procedure is done for every stage of an cascade.

Unfortunately for every object those features are not the same (different size although you have fixed number of feature shapes), thus a feature space is not the same either.
So even that there is a way to combine those classifiers, the benefit would be marginal because you probably do not have the same features for different objects so you would need evaluate almost every feature again.

Answer (score 0):

I run each of mine as a separate parallel task.

Comment: That really does not give me that much of a speedup. I am not sure if I am doing it wrong. I use boost::thread_group to run 6 trained haar-cascades. After I added them to the group I call join_all() to run them and wait for all of them to finish.

In comparison though I get this result (Core 2 Quad with 3 GHz and 4 Gb Ram): 

6 Cascades: Parallel: 1,16s, Normal: 1,45s |
9 Cascades: Parallel: 1,4s,  Normal: 1,85s |
12 Cascades: Parallel: 1,68s, Normal: 2,14S |

I use high resolution images (1920x1080) with preprocessing to limit the areas I am using my cascades on.

Comment: But what you are doing it waiting for **all** the threads to end so it will not provide that much of a speed up.

What you should be doing is processing each thread as they end - this will speed things up for you. Also, try to calculate which thread will take the longest and run that one first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't wait for all but process each as they end by raising an event.